# Should I create the different table for each specific list in ToDo app?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

There is `MainActivity` with `RecyclerView` and `FloatingButton` that allows to create `CardView` dynamically within that `RecyclerView`. Each `CardView` is a name for user's tasks list. So that if the user clicks that `CardView`, He goes to `DetailedListActivity` and sees and also can create specific tasks for that list.

My question is that should I create different Tables for each list in MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

add one table for the `TaskLists` and one table for the `Tasks`.

ordinary a `ViewPager` is being used for `TaskLists` and a `RecyclerView` for the `Tasks`

... where the detail-view should probably be one `Task`.

also see the [Google Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/tasks/), eg. for synchronization.

Comment: You mean create table for storing tables for tasks list and then the table of specific tasks that is referenced to the list table?

Comment: @SeymurAyvazov yes, this is the least required and the least effort.. and then `SELECT` by `WHERE taskListId = ?` in order to get the items of a single `TaskList`.